# Integral of rational function

Tags: integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integration of $\int\frac{1}{x^{4}+1}dx$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160157/integration-of-int-frac1x41dx)

We are asked to find the following anti-derivative
$$\int \frac{dx}{1+x^4}$$

I tried partial fraction decomposition but I did not manage. How can I obtain the solution for the integral above?