# Proof $1 -\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{13} + ... = \frac{\pi + 2\ln(1+\sqrt2)}{4\sqrt2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to show that

$$1 -\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{13} + \cdots = \frac{\pi + 2\ln(1+\sqrt2)}{4\sqrt2}.$$

I thought of using the power series for $\tanh^{-1}z$ which I found was $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ and playing with $z=i^{3/2}$ but I get some unwanted terms that I can't get rid of...

Can you help me please?

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+a}=\frac{H\Big(\frac{a-1}2\Big)-H\Big(\frac a2-1\Big)}2,~$ where $H(k)$ is the $k^{th}$ [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{4n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1(-1)^nx^{4n}dx=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^4}$$

To evaluate this integral, see, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/619660/39285) answer.

Comment: Well spotted. (I.e., I wish I'd see it before you! ;-) )

Comment: I get something very similar but that includes $coth^{-1}$

Comment: Remember $arccoth(x) = arctanh(1/x)$. Alternatively, you can write $arccoth$ or $arctanh$ as $\ln(something)$, just by solving

$$y = \frac{ e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$ for $x$

Comment: Thank you, it solves the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You may use your idea too and write the expansion of :
\begin{align}
\arctan(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
\operatorname{arctanh}(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
\end{align}
so that 
$$\frac 12(\arctan(z)+\operatorname{arctanh}(z))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$$

Noting that $\;\arctan(z)=-i\,\operatorname{arctanh}(i\,z))\,$ and searching a root of $z^4=-1$ should help you to conclude... especially if you remember that $\;\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=\dfrac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}2$.

Comment: How do you get rid of the $\sum \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}{4n+1}$ term that evaluating $\sum \frac{z^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$ at $z=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$ gives?

Comment: Does the edit answer my question? I did remember that

Comment: @Dollydot: not entirely :-)... well this is merely a multiplicative constant and you may multiply by $e^{-i\frac {\pi}4}$ at the end but I didn't compute the whole thing yet... (the numerical result is right)

Comment: I'll try to keep going a little, maybe I can lead it to its end!

Comment: @Dollydot: it simplifies at the end since $\dfrac{1+e^{i\frac{\pi}4}}{1-e^{i\frac{\pi}4}}=i\,(1+\sqrt{2})\;$ and $\dfrac{1+i\,e^{i\frac{\pi}4}}{1-i\,e^{i\frac{\pi}4}}=i\,(\sqrt{2}-1)\;$ if I my computations are right but I'll agree that these computations are a bit lengthy... I am fine with the other answer anyway! :-) Excellent continuation,