# $\int {e^{3x} - e^x \over e^{4x} + e^{2x} + 1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$I = \int {e^{3x} - e^x \over e^{4x} + e^{2x} + 1} dx$$

Substituting for $e^x$,

$$I = \int {u^2 - 1 \over u^4 + u^2 + 1} du = \int { u^4 + u^2 + 1 + - 2 - u^4 \over u^4 + u^2 + 1} du = u - \int {u^4 + 2 \over u^4 + u^2 + 1} du $$

Now I don't know anything I can do to last integral except partial fraction decomposition but I am pretty sure that $u^4 + u^2 + 1$ does not have any factors in real numbers.

Is this integral computable on real numbers ? How do I compute it ?

Comment: $u^4+u^2+1$, like any real polynomial with no real roots, can be factored into irreducible quadratic factors. In this case they should be straightforward to calculate. (Also you lost a minus sign.)

Comment: @Ian How can I find those factors ? I literally plugged every number from 1 to 10.

Comment: It is easy to factor $u^4+u^2+1$ over $\mathbb{C}$ because it is just $v^2+v+1$ where $v=u^2$, so each root is one of the square roots of the roots of $v^2+v+1$. Then you can multiply out the linear factors corresponding to conjugate roots to get irreducible quadratic factors. (This is not the only way to do it of course.)

Comment: @Ian With any polynomial do you mean polynomial with 4th degree or just any nth degree polynomial ?

Comment: Technically any real polynomial will do, but if the degree is higher than 4 then you may not have a closed form for the roots and thus for the factorization.

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't actually need tedious Partial Fraction Decomposition as

$$\dfrac{u^2-1}{u^4+Au^2+1}=\dfrac{1-\dfrac1{u^2}}{u^2+A+\dfrac1{u^2}}$$ where $A$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now as $\displaystyle\int\left(1-\dfrac1{u^2}\right)du=u+\dfrac1u,$

write $\displaystyle u^2+A+\dfrac1{u^2}=\left(u+\dfrac1u\right)^2+A-2$ and set $u+\dfrac1u=v$

Comment: Nice trick! ${}{}$

Comment: How did you do this ? Is this a standard trick ?

Comment: @A---B,   See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426152/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracdx1x4/426194#426194  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160157/integration-of-int-frac1x41-mathrm-dx/619652#619652

Comment: Oh nice thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $$u^4 + u^2 + 1 = (u^4 + 2u^2 + 1) - u^2 = (u^2 + 1)^2 - u^2 = (u^2 + u + 1)(u^2 - u + 1).$$  From this, we try a partial fraction decomposition of the form $$\frac{Au + B}{u^2 - u + 1} + \frac{Cu + D}{u^2 + u + 1} = \frac{u^2 - 1}{u^4 + u^2 + 1},$$ and after multiplying out and comparing like coefficients of $u$, we have $$\begin{align*} A + C &= 0 \\ A+B-C+D &= 1 \\
A+B+C-D &= 0 \\
B+D &= -1. \end{align*}$$  From here, we get $$B = D = -1/2,$$ and $$A = 1, C = -1.$$  Consequently, the integrand becomes $$\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{2u-1}{u^2-u+1} - \frac{2u+1}{u^2+u+1}\right),$$ and the rest is straightforward.  As a bonus, you even find that the numerator of each term is the derivative of the respective denominator.  You can't get much nicer than that.

Comment: Thank you very much I did not know it can be factorised.