# How do I compute the complex partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{z^5-1}{z^4+1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have the following question

I need to compute the complex partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{z^5-1}{z^4+1}$. After a first long division I get $\frac{z^5-1}{z^4+1}=z-\frac{z+1}{z^4+1}$,now I only need to continue with the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{z+1}{z^4+1}$ but here I'm somehow stuck. My idea was to solve $z^4=-1$ so I would like to solve $e^{4i\Theta}=e^{i\pi}$.
so I got now that $z^4+1=\left(z+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(z-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(z-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(z+\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ right?

Could maybe someone help me?

Comment: It works the exact same way as in real analysis, except easier: all your factors are linear. How would you decompose a real valued rational function $\frac{x+1}{p(x)}$ with a degree 4 polynomial function $p$?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos so I added above that I would like to find the roots of $z^4+1$ or in your case $p(x)$

Comment: Maybe not relevant to the actual question, but in your long division you forgot to include the *quotient* in the equality that you wrote (which is certainly not true as it currently stands).

Comment: @HansLundmark perfect thanks

Comment: OK, but now the remainder has the wrong sign. Anyway, I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/901566/1242) should resolve your problem.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos so I got now that $z^4+1=\left(z+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(z-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(z-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(z+\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to leave the roots in symbolic form.

You have already established that $$\frac{z^5 - 1}{z^4 + 1} = z - \frac{z + 1}{z^4 + 1}.$$  Then let the roots of $z^4 + 1 = 0$ be $$r_k = e^{(2k-1) \pi i/4}, \quad k \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}.$$  We then seek coefficients $A_k \in \mathbb C$ satisfying
$$\frac{z + 1}{z^4 + 1} = \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{A_k}{z - r_k}.$$  To this end we employ the "cover-up" method arising from the fact that when the RHS is expressed over the common denominator $z^4 + 1$, the numerator is the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^4 A_k \prod_{j \ne k} (z - r_j) = A_1 (z - r_2)(z - r_3)(z - r_4) + A_2 (z - r_1)(z-r_3)(z-r_4) + \cdots,$$ where each product of linear factors excludes the factor with $r_k$ as a root.  Hence by choosing $z = r_k$ in the above expression for each $k$, we obtain the successive identities
$$\begin{align}
r_1 + 1 &= A_1(r_1 - r_2)(r_1 - r_3)(r_1 - r_4), \\ 
r_2 + 1 &= A_2(r_2 - r_1)(r_2 - r_3)(r_2 - r_4), \\
r_3 + 1 &= A_3(r_3 - r_1)(r_3 - r_2)(r_3 - r_4), \\ 
r_4 + 1 &= A_4(r_4 - r_1)(r_4 - r_2)(r_4 - r_3), \\
\end{align}$$
or more generally,
$$r_k + 1 = A_k \prod_{j \ne k} (r_k - r_j),$$ hence
$$A_k = \frac{r_k + 1}{\prod_{j \ne k} (r_k - r_j)} = \frac{e^{(2k-1)\pi i/4} + 1}{\prod_{j \ne k} (e^{(2k-1) \pi i/4} - e^{(2j-1) \pi i/4})}.$$
All that remains is to evaluate this expression:  for instance,
$$A_1 = \frac{e^{\pi i/4} + 1}{(e^{\pi i/4} - e^{3\pi i/4})(e^{\pi i/4} - e^{-\pi i/4})(e^{\pi i/4} - e^{-3\pi i/4})} = \frac{1}{2(1 - \sqrt{2} + i)}.$$  The rest I leave as an exercise.