# How do we integrate $\dfrac{1}{1+x^4}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am still confused with this integral: $\int \dfrac{1}{1+x^4}dx$

There one solution was given by a pupil that we write it as $\dfrac{x^2+1-(x^2-1)}{2(1+x^4)}$

Then split into two terms and proceed by putting $x+{1\over x}=t$ and completing the square.

My question is can we approach this question using other technique, most obviously **partial fraction**? The roots are complex, so how do we deal with it? Also please tell me a general procedure for such questions! Thank You!

Comment: You'll need to use techniques from complex analysis if you factor in terms of complex roots, specifically the residue theorem.

Comment: Only partial fractions are required, as the integral is indefinite, so there is no need for evaluating residues.

Comment: To use partial fractions with only real roots, we would have to note that
$$
x^4 + 1 = (x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1)(x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1)
$$

Comment: Related questions, maybe useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426152/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracdx1x4 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43457/how-can-i-compute-the-integral-int-0-infty-fracdt1t4?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: And this! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160157/integration-of-int-frac1x41-mathrm-dx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For partial fractions factor into quadratics (this is the hard part):
$$x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)$$

Do the standard decomposition method with undetermined cofficients:

$$\frac{1}{x^4+1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{2}}{x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1}
-\frac{x-\sqrt{2}}{x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1}
\right)$$

Integrate:
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^4+1}=
\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\ln \left(\frac{x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1}{x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1}\right)
+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}((\arctan(\sqrt{2}x+1)+\arctan(\sqrt{2}x-1))$$

I think its quite beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2-2x^2=(x^2+1-\sqrt{2}x)(x^2+1+\sqrt{2}x)$$